# Widgets not showing in Android 4.0+

Tags: android, android-widget, adt

I have a basic clock widget here, it works just fine on versions of android below 4.0, you can long press, select widgets and its right there. But when i try to run it on 4.0 or later emulator or real device, it does not show up in widgets section only in Settings>Storage>Apps. I have tried adding a simple activity that just gives users directions on how to install the widget , that suggestion was given as an answer here: [Android 4.0: widgets not appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794952/android-4-0-widgets-not-appearing)  . Unless i did it wrong the widget still does not show up in widget drawer.

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.widgetexample1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />                
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".ExampleAppWidgetProvider"
            android:label="8-bit cloud widget 1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/widget1_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Still haven't found a solution, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794952/android-4-0-widgets-not-appearing
i've the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

add below in your manifest.xml.
"android:exported="true".
it might help.
try it.

Comment: Added it in <Activity ..... > section, no different, app shows up in App drawer but nowhere to be seen in widget tray. Seems like others post 4.0 have this issue, but no concrete answers....

Comment: Added <category android:name="android.intent.category.GADGET" />

to the <intent-filter> section, still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

In your widget metadata xml file check tag `<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` android:xmlns attribute should start with `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are being hit by a security upgrade which I think happened in HoneyComb.

Basically, in newer versions of Android, you cannot have your widget working, without first launching an `Activity`.

So add an activity to the project, run it first, and I think your widgets will update.

A good example would be to use a Settings style activity, or perhaps and About box type of thing, to tell the user a bit about your widget. (I use settings in my widgets).

---

For more info:

- [Android 4.0: widgets not appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794952/android-4-0-widgets-not-appearing)