# android widget not showing in the widget list - jellybean

Tags: android, android-widget

I am working on the home screen widget in an android app.  When I installed it in nexus 10 tablet the widget is not showing in the widget list, and I am getting the following error in the logcat.

```
AppsCustomizedPagedView   “Widget ComponentInfo(com.abc.yyy/com.abc.yyy.widgetProvider) cannot fit on this device(1400, 1200)”
```

It is happening on only nexus 10. In other tablets like samsung and motorola(both are having ics) are working fine

We have tried the following to get the widget on the widget list

1. checked whether it is installed in tablet's memory or SD card. It is present in tablet's memory.
2. created an launcher activity. The launcher is visible in app list but the widget is not visible in widgets list.
3. Added the android:widgetCategory="home" in widgetprovider.xml
4. Added the send broadcast from MainActivity like given in the link below

[Android 4.0: widgets not appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794952/android-4-0-widgets-not-appearing/8866791#8866791)

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME));
```

Nothing worked any idea. why widget is not showing in the widget list.

Comment: The exception you are getting is because of the minimum width and height size that you have define for your widget in widget info xml is too much for this device.

Try reducing the min_height and min_width and you should be able to see your widget in the list.

Comment: I answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948682/android-widget-not-showing-up-on-the-list-after-developed/17378804#17378804, verify if it not solve :)

Answer (score 0):

working for me:-

It somehow causes problem with widget list if the app is installed on SD
just install in phone storage and show its will be show in widget list