# Homescreen Widget doesn't get installed

Tags: android, widget, installation, homescreen

I have a simple application and I want a homescreen widget (an Image) that runs the app from one of the activities, not exactly the Main Activity. 
I have no errors in the compilation, running the app or installing it, but the widget isn't installed neither in a tablet or a phone I am using for testing. 
So... this is what I am doing.

widget_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout" 
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:configure=".MyWidgetProvider"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:updatePeriodMillis="3000" >    
</appwidget-provider>
```

widget_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="146dp"
    android:layout_height="146dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dip"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >    
</LinearLayout>
```

MyWidgetProvider.java

```
package com.project;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {


  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {


      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);

      ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context,MyWidgetProvider.class);
      AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
      manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);


  }
}
```

And this is the receiver inside Application in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="Detente" >
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                 <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
 </receiver>
```

Do I need to add any permission or something like that or maybe this "android:installLocation="preferExternal"" is causing conflict?

(I'm running the tests on a Lenovo Tab whit ICS and a LG 3D-Max with GB )

I need this for tomorrow, please help. :D

Comment: Does your logcat say anything when you try to add the widget on the device?

Comment: I'm. trying to add the widget by tapholding in the homescreen but it is not in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was as simple as moving the application to the device... it was being installed to the SD because of this

```
 android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

Keep in mind that the widgets can only be installed if the app is in the internal memory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that you have not declared your AppWidgetProvider correctly.

As per the [App Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) guide,

> The  element requires the android:name attribute, which
>   specifies the AppWidgetProvider used by the App Widget.

Your AppWidgetProvider is called `MyWidgetProvider`, but your manifest says `<receiver android:name="Detente" >`. Changing this to `<receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >` may solve your problem.

I also do not see an `ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER` in the [AppWidgetManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html). Where did that come from? The documentation indicates that only `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` is required.

Comment: Changed it, but the widget still missing in the list.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a note about your `ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER`, which may also be causing problems.

Comment: Do you have a configuration activity and/or a launcher activity? [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8866791/1253844) for some possible other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but yes, I have more than one activity, and they're all running well. The apps works fine, no errors, no logcat red lines and of course no app widget in the widgets' list.