# Android JAVA Widget does not show up in the list of widgets

Tags: java, android, widget

I've been trying to create a basic app widget and cannot get it to show in the widget list.

Code is below:

Widget_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="8dip"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/update"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:text="@string/click_to_configure" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Widget_info.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:minWidth="146dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1000" 
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
android:configure="com.promethylhosting.countdowntowidget.SettingsActivity"
/>
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.promethylhosting.countdowntowidget"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


 <activity 
     android:name=".SettingsActivity"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="Countdown to... Widget"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name=".ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>

        </intent-filter> 

     <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
         <!--  mulitple actions must have multiple action filters 1:1 ratio between       action/filter --> 
    </activity> 

    <reciever
        android:name="CountdownToWidgetProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Countdown To Widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </reciever>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I've been googling around and did not find any solution which resolved this issue. So I'm posting here.

Thank you in advance for reading this and advice.

Edit: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your main activity, There is always a problem showing widget in list of 4.0

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
       .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME));
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



}
```

also take a reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794952/android-4-0-widgets-not-appearing)

Comment: I have this code currently in place in the MAIN/LAUNCHER :  

try {
        sendBroadcast(new     Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME));
        } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.wtf(LOG_TAG, "Trying to activate widget, I Get... something: " + e.getMessage());
        }