# Android AVD... where is the widget list?

Tags: android, list, widget, emulation

I have developed an Android App that runs fine on emulator & on device. Now I´m trying to develope a Widget but I am unable to see it on emulator. I searched in this forum and I found this thread [Android 4.0: widgets not appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794952/android-4-0-widgets-not-appearing) where JamieB had posted a solution that worked for me when running widget on device but emulator does not show yet the widget.

I found too another threads where people posted that "go to widget list and launch widget from there", but I cannot see widget list on my emulator which leads me to think that something I am doing wrong when creating the AVD.

I´m using 4.4W platform, 20 API level.

Is there a special way to create an AVD in order to see "widget list" on it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use avd with api level19 4.4. api20 4.4W is kitkat for watches and it gave me also many headaches like you because it's designed for wear devices like watches.

Comment: Yes, it worked! I have installed 4.4.2 platform API 19 then I have created a new AVD and now I can see it like a real cell phone with its menus, buttons and widgets too. Thank you so much, I wasted a long of time on this issue. But anyway it is a rare thing, API 20 should have this also in addition to support for wear devices.